# URL noob - Is this a specific kind of url? ie RFC 1738?

Tags: url, rfc

If i have a url structured like this:

```
<scheme> : <path> ? <key> = <parameter> & <otherkey> = <otherparamet>
```

is that a specific 'type' of URL? Im trying to figure out if this conforms to RFC 1738

Comment: Is that the whole URL or are you just showing the punctuation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are URL's formatted like this:

```
http://www.example.com/search.php?name=jeremy&state=oh
```

In this case, the `?` starts the query and the `&` separates the parameters.

The parameters are URIComponentEncoded and may look a bit funny.

Comment: basically im wondering if a url without the slashes is its own rfc type

Answer (score 0):

I think you're leaving stuff out....  Using those delimiters you gave and in that order, I can construct an HTTP GET request to a specific port, supplying two named identifiers with data values.

```
http://some.domain.com:portnumber?key1=value1&key2=value2
```